# Proving a function f(x) is logarithmic via its domain/range and derivitives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've been trying to prove to myself that $\begin{equation} \frac {d}{dx} \end{equation} a^x = a^xln(a)$, and have come across a snag with figuring out how to prove $\begin{equation}ln(a) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} \end{equation}$ without using any prior calculus knowledge, save for how to derive basic derivitive rules for polynomials and trig functions.

What I've been able to derive so far is that $\begin{equation} \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} \end{equation}$ is the slope of $\begin{equation} a^x \end{equation}$ at zero, which I can approximate and anylize to figure out that if if $\begin{equation} d(x) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{x^h-1}{h} \end{equation}$:

1. $\begin{equation} d(x) \end{equation}$ must be defined and continuous for $\begin{equation} (0, \infty) \end{equation}$
2. $\begin{equation} d(x) \end{equation}$ shares a reversed domain and range with $\begin{equation} a^x \end{equation}$
3. $\begin{equation} d'(x) > 0 \end{equation}$
4. $\begin{equation} d''(x) < 0 \end{equation}$
5. $\begin{equation} d(1) = 0 \end{equation}$

Out of all of these, the second seems to be the one with the most promise, but I simply can't find anything more than a basic explanation of inverse functions online or hyper dense mathematics talk that ends up just assuming that $\begin{equation} \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} = ln(a) \end{equation}$, which isn't helpful.

Comment: Your formula is not correct. It should be $\frac{d}{dx}a^x=a^x\ln a$ with $a$ being a positive real number. So might want to revise your statement.

Comment: All of this depends on definition of $a^x$ and $\log a$. One approach is to define $\log a$ via limit $\log a=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}$ given some definition of $a^x$.

Comment: What is your _definition_ of $\ln x$? If you've defined it as inverse of $e^x$, then using some manipulations, you can arrive at the limit.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak thanks, fixed

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I could do that, but it would defeat the entire purpose of this exercise as I'm trying to find a way to justify that $\begin{equation} log_a (n) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} \end{equation}$, where n is some real number.

Comment: @DS I don't have a definitiion of $\begin{equation} ln(x) \end{equation}$ right now, I'm just trying to prove that  $\begin{equation} d(x) \end{equation}$ is logarithmic in nature so I can define $\begin{equation} d(a) \end{equation}$ as $\begin{equation} log_n(a) \end{equation}$ and attempt to solvle for n at some later point.

Comment: The derivative of $a^x$ is **not** logarithmic in nature, but it is exponential. You're fighting a lost battle here.

Comment: Hang on, are you trying to prove $\frac d{dx} a^x = a^x \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h -1}{h}$?

Comment: Which is just the limit representation of the derivative, with $a^x$ factored out.

Comment: Well in that case you can directly prove that $d'(x) =1/x,d(1)=0$ which sort of identifies it uniquely.

Comment: @DS I've already proven that $\begin{equation} \frac {d}{dx} \end{equation} a^x = a^x\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h}$ via plugging $\begin{equation} a^x \end{equation}$ into the derivative formula. I'm trying to prove that $\begin{equation} \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} \end{equation}$ is equivalent to some logarithmic function.

Comment: @DS And I suspect this because of point 2 in my post, as that screams inverse function, and the graph of $\begin{equation} d(x) \end{equation}$ seems to reflect that of $\begin{equation} a^x \end{equation}$. I just need a way to prove, if possible, those two are inverses using the information in the list.

Comment: Here is further hint: prove that $d(xy) =d(x) +d(y) $ and $d(x) \leq x-1,\forall x>0$. This can be used to prove $d'(x) =1/x$.

Comment: Depends on how you categorise "logarithmic" functions, without a definition of logarithm. If you mean "logarithmic" is the inverse of "exponential", try to derive the inverse of $e^x = \lim _{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1x \right)^x$